# Searching in 2 lists with a single search field

Tags: tables, search, search-results

In my system, I initially had a single table of users with a simple search field that would filter the table on whatever input was given.

Now I extended this table with a group selection on the left of the table. User can create these groups, and add the user under the correct group.

[image]

The problem I now have though is that the search filter doesn't really make sense. Say for example i search on "*Mary*" It currently will do this:

[image]

This is how it worked before, and how it worked on other tables in the system as well. But then I realized, with the addition of the group selection on the left: *What if there other Mary's in the other groups?*

Likewise, say i search on a "Michael", a user that's in a different group than the one is currently selected:

[image]

This gives the impression that there's no user named Michael in the system, but what if there was a Michael under the R&D group?

---

So a two solutions I thought of:

**1) Add a super of the amount of results in a group**
[image]

**2) Don't show results automatically, but show a dropdown with results that the user must select**

[image]

Comment: Can a single user be in different groups?

Comment: By name yes, but not by mail (must be unique)

Comment: One thing to consider is that I think you need to tell the user what group their search results belong to. If there is a Mary in HR and a different Mary in R&D, how would the user know which Mary belongs to what? I would have a way to explicitly show the user which Mary belongs to what category.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misconception.

The search field you're referring to is about a user, not a user within a group, so the user search result should be independent of the group search.

If I search for "Mary" all "Marys" should come up, with no groups selected with some sort of indicator as to which groups contain those "marys". The fact of looking for a "Mary" within a group ceases to be a simple filter to be a *criteria filter*.

In a filter with variables you can select a group first and search for a user in this group exclusively:

[image]

If there is no group selected, the search result is complete, showing which groups have been activated in the search and which have been added to the search criteria, allowing you to remove the one not required:

[image]